# Getting contact names and phone numbers in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I know this has been asked a lot, yet I'm struggling to find a full solution and the few I find are in Objective C

I have managed to get this far

```
public static func refreshContacts(){
    let status = ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus()
    if status == .Denied || status == .Restricted {
        // user previously denied, to tell them to fix that in settings
        return
    }

    // open it

    var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
    let addressBook: ABAddressBook? = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, &error)?.takeRetainedValue()
    if addressBook == nil {
        println(error?.takeRetainedValue())
        return
    }

    // request permission to use it

    ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook) {
        granted, error in

        if !granted {
            // warn the user that because they just denied permission, this functionality won't work
            // also let them know that they have to fix this in settings
            return
        }

        if let people = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook)?.takeRetainedValue() as? NSArray {
            for person in people{
                var name = //??????
                var phoneumber = //??????
            }

        }
    }
}
```

If you read the comment, you can see there is one point where I am not too sure what to do
How can i get the name and phone numbers?

Comment: So what do you need - example code? Here is some: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch18p713addressBook/ch31p973addressBook/ViewController.swift But bear in mind that's Swift 1.2 and iOS 8. In iOS 9 this whole sorry-assed framework will finally be retired.

Comment: @matt thank goodness. It is pretty bad, the framework. Do you have any ios9 exmaples? Also the exmalple you posted doesnt have phone numbers

Comment: I'm showing you an example. Think about it and learn from it. I get paid extra if you want me to write _your_ code _for_ you! :)

Comment: @matt haha thanks. I've managed to adapt it, ill post an answer here in a min

Comment: And I upvoted your answer! It's good that those `takeRetainedValue` calls didn't drive you insane... :)

Comment: @matt to be honest, I'm not too sure what takeRetainedValue does, but it works. I'll look it up later

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a solution

```
public static func refreshContacts(){
    let status = ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus()
    if status == .Denied || status == .Restricted {
        // user previously denied, to tell them to fix that in settings
        return
    }

    // open it

    var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
    let addressBook: ABAddressBook? = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, &error)?.takeRetainedValue()
    if addressBook == nil {
        println(error?.takeRetainedValue())
        return
    }

    // request permission to use it

    ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook) {
        granted, error in

        if !granted {
            // warn the user that because they just denied permission, this functionality won't work
            // also let them know that they have to fix this in settings
            return
        }

        if let people = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook)?.takeRetainedValue() as? NSArray {
            for person in people{
                if let name = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty).takeRetainedValue() as? String {
                    println(name)//persons name
                }
                let numbers:ABMultiValue = ABRecordCopyValue(
                    person, kABPersonPhoneProperty).takeRetainedValue()
                for ix in 0 ..< ABMultiValueGetCount(numbers) {
                    let label = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(numbers,ix).takeRetainedValue() as String
                    let value = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(numbers,ix).takeRetainedValue() as! String
                    println("Phonenumber \(label) is \(value))
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

adapted from https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch18p713addressBook/ch31p973addressBook/ViewController.swift